# Android: resizing font in square TextView

Tags: android, textview, text-size

A TextView has the form of a big square on the screen. The text inside has to be resized so it is as big as possible and fits the entire TextView space.

Let's say the text is "hello", the result will be a big "hello" on the screen.

I am asking here how to resize the font to the right pixel amount, provided the square has a known size.

I know the displayed string cannot be perfectly squared but the main goal is that the text is as big as possible, within the TextView area.

Comment: Do you have some code we can work with for a start?

Comment: @Roman Rozenshtein It's just the font size I'm concerned, I do not need suggestions about the other things

Answer (score 0):

```
Override following method:

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        // the height will be set at this point
        int height = myEverySoTallView.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        int width = myEverySoTallView.getMeasuredWidth();

        //as per width/height you can try modifying text size
        myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, width/SOME_CONSTANT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want the text to be drawn normally (as in a 0 degree rotation), but scale to meet the boundaries of the View, you can use something like this:

```
public class ScalingTextCustomTextView extends CustomTextView {

    public ScalingTextCustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScalingTextCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        refitText(this.getText().toString(), parentWidth);

        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before, final int after) {
        refitText(text.toString(), this.getWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        if(w != oldw)
            refitText(this.getText().toString(), w);
    }

    private void refitText(String text, int textWidth) {
        if(textWidth <= 0)
            return;

        int targetWidth = textWidth - this.getPaddingLeft() - this.getPaddingRight();
        float hi = 200;
        float lo = 2;
        final float threshold = 0.5f;

        Paint temp = new Paint();
        temp.set(getPaint());

        while((hi - lo) > threshold){
            float size = (hi + lo) / 2;
            temp.setTextSize(size);

            if(temp.measureText(text) >= targetWidth)
                hi = size;
            else lo = size;
        }

        this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lo);
    }
}`
```

If you want it to rotate 45 degrees, you can just add:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(45, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

But if you want that to scale slightly larger to fit the longest distance, you'd have to adjust refitText to calculate the target width based on the distance from top-left to bottom-right.

This should point you in the right direction, though.

Comment: The square has a known and fixed size, it is not modified in real-time, my question arises because characters have different size, so a word would be different from another. Forget also rotation because the text rotates too. However I edited my question.

Comment: The ScalingTextCustomTextView in my answer actually applies to that case as well. It refits the textsize to fit the View whenever the text changes or the size of the view changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is enough to set the desired textView size (myTextViewSize), then set the text content (it is inside for sure with my desired view dimensions),

then use

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
int oldTextWidth=bounds.width();
float oldFontSize=textView.getTextSize();
float newFontSize=(myTextViewSize- textView.getPaddingLeft() - textView.getPaddingRight())*oldFontSize/oldTextWidth;
```